# Light weight mechanism for encrypting sqlite database on android without shipping customized sqlite distibution

Tags: android, database, sqlite, encryption, android-sqlite

I am building one android application where I want to maintain certain details in the sqlite database. I am using SQLiteOpenHelper interface in order to maintain single instance of the database for all the threads accessing the database.

For security reasons I want to encrypt my database because if the database file is not encrypted, it is possible to view the database file on rooted android devices.
To avoid this I want to encrypt the database file.
I have gone through SEE, wxSQLite, SQLiteCrypt and botansqlite3 but they all require cutomized distribution of SQLite to be shipped onto android device.
I want to secure my database file with the normal distribution of SQLite that is shipped with Android.

Also I tried to use SQLCipher but it increases my application's total size by 8-10MB. One more reason for not using SQLCipher is that it doesn't support mips architecure (but this could be built later on with some modifications in the source code).

Also my database will be accessed and updated by many threads and will be loaded all the time by a service so decrypting database at the time of loading/opening and encrypting at the time of unloading/closing will not work for me. It should be possible to fire queries on encrypted database only or there should be some alternative solution like creating temp database, decrypting it and performing operations on it.

Can anyone suggest me a light weight solution for encrypting SQLite database on android devices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On a rooted device, the encryption key can be read out of your app. How would you prevent that?

Comment: I can accept the key from user at runtime but if any other better solution is there then its wonderful. Also I can obfuscate the code of my application so as to make decompiling more difficult.